# How to transfer music from iPod Touch to computer?

Tags: windows-7, ipod-touch

How do I copy all my music from my old iPod Touch to the computer/iTunes on Windows 7, so I can put it on my new iPod Touch?

Answer (score 2):

There's a free application called [SharePod](http://www.getsharepod.com/) specifically designed to do this (to transfer music from an iPod to a PC).

I use SharePod as a convenient way to copy mp3s that I own from my home PC (where I originally copied the music from PC to iPod, using iTunes) to my work PC.

**Update January 2014** - As of the latest version, SharePod v4, it looks like SharePod is no longer free, unfortunately.

Comment: It looks like this would work, but it only copied 50 tracks. I'd have to pay $20 to copy all of the tracks.

Comment: @CsabaToth It looks like SharePod has become no longer free since the time I originally posted this. :-(  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

go into `My Computer`, right-click on your device, click `Copy`, navigate to the place on your HD that you want the files, right-click, and click `Paste`.
Very simple!
You can also paste the data directly onto the new device, instead of using your HD.

Note: This doesn't work with iPod Touch, only with older iPods.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, since this would work - the files are stored *right on the iPod file system*.  They're renamed, but they still have all of the ID3 tags.

Comment: yep. the iPod (to the computer) is just a fancy external HD

Comment: iPod != iPod Touch. In forums I see that this matters a lot. I don't see my iPod Touch as a drive. I just want to download the music from a Touch, nothing more. I've even installed iTunes, I'm using Win 8.1.